# Using git to fetch commit ids between certain dates or a specific time period from a remote repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to write a bash script that would be pushed to a repository.
Typically I would clone this repo and run the script.

What I need the script to do is take a user input which specifies the time period and it would fetch all the commit ids between that time period for the other repos that I have specified (I am maintaining a separate file for the list of repos that I am interested in)

I have tried the following from the repo:

```
 git ls-remote --heads <git repo> | grep refs/heads/master | cut -f 1
 ===> gives me the commit id

 git rev-parse --short <commit id>
 ===> gives me the short commit id

 git rev-list --oneline --date-order <short commit id> --since="2daysago"
 ===> throws an error

 fatal: ambiguous argument '<shortcommitid>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
 Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Is there a way I could fetch the commit ids for a remote branch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### git rev-list

As far as I know there is no equivalent command to `git-rev-list` that operates on a remote instead of a local repo.

So **it is in any case needed to fetch the remote repo to local** to obtain what you want.

Working on the local copy you could give a command like:

```
git rev-list --oneline --date-order --since="2 days ago" $(cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master)
```

**NOTE**

- 'days' and 'ago' must be separate words in the *--since* option (and you can skip 'ago' if you prefer)

---

### limit git fetch to commits since a date

You can also consider to use `git fetch --shallow-since` (see [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---shallow-sinceltdategt)):

```
git fetch --shallow-since="2 days ago"
```

so that the only fetched commits are the ones you are interested in...
after this you could give the previous command or what else you need to do with these commits

---

### UPDATE

perhaps this could be similar to what you want:

```
# foreach repourl
git fetch --shallow-since="2 days ago" <repourl>    # it downloads just commits and objects of last days
git rev-list --oneline --date-order --since="2 days ago" $(cat .git/FETCH_HEAD | cut -f 1)
rm -rf .git/objects   #if you are interested only to the IDs
```